# Installing semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css is not working in react app

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to use semantic-ui-react in my react-app, but the moment I import the following statement it takes a lot of time to compile and then ultimately throws an error.

I did the following steps:
npm install semantic-ui-react
npm install semantic-ui-css

import 'semantic-UI-css/semantic.min.css'

I know this is the issue because everything works if I comment this import statement.

My package.json looks like below:
"dependencies": {
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.26",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
}
Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: i am getting the same error.